# Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Tags: docker, tty, mobaxterm

I am using Mobaxterm and starting a local bash terminal, and trying this command. But seeing an error. The same command is working from the cmd windows prompt or powershell. Any suggestions on workarounds, really appreciate it. I played with some settings that are already in the mobaxterm, but none worked.

```
/home/mobaxterm>docker login abcdef.azurecr.io
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

Answer (score 11):

Try adding `winpty` before the `docker ...` command.

It enables TTY on Windows. Useful for GitBash, Putty and MobaXTerm.

```
$ winpty docker login $ACR_REGISTRY
Username: appacr
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

Comment: Does anyone know the MacOS equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

This is a docker error. Each Repo needs to have it's own environment variables set up. If you don't set up the DOCKER_USERNAME and DOCKER_PASSWORD in your model in the Repository settings, it would raise that confusing docker terminal (tty) error.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--password-stdin` flag as specified in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/docker-basics.html).

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was with AWS ECR and I simply needed to update my aws cli.

AWS-CLI, version 2 installation instructions for Mac:
`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html`

You'll find similar instructions for other OS's there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the region in the `aws ecr` statement such as this example provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html):

`aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com`

When I tried this to resolve the error I also noticed that AWS is finicky (unwilling to accept reasonable mistakes, for the non-english-native users) about how you define the region variable though. For example, `us-west-2`, while good enough in the `--password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com` part of the call, needed to be specified further as `us-west-2b` within the `aws ecr get-login-password --region region` portion of the command.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue on m1 Mac and the solution is refreshing the artifactory token.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider expanding your answer by adding instructions on _how_ to do this. Also, you may want to explain why you think the token is the cause behind the OP's problem.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Your answer is a bit terse and could be improved by explaining the issue, i.e., the underlying cause of the problem and why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question.