# Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device when login in GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github

When I am using this command to login docker in GitHub Actions:

```
docker login --username=${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }} --password=${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }} registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
```

shows error:

```
Run docker login --username=*** --*** registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

what should I do to fix this problem? This is my full GitHub Action CI script:

```
- name: Build image push to aliyun
  run: |
    docker login --username=${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }} --password=${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }} registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
    docker build -f dolphin-acientbay/Dockerfile -t="${namespace}/dolphin-acientbay-service:v1.0.0" .
```

runs on Ubuntu operation system.

Comment: Does [winpty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571773/117549) help at all?

Comment: Does the [`--password-stdin` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) help at all?

Comment: I will try later @JeffSchaller r I am tried to use action script now

Answer (score 1):

It will decide that the interactive login is required if the secrets.* stuff is not actually set. To test, try to substitute the values for the actual username and password.